# how to extract coordinates of bounding box?

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am working in android with kotlin and I'm making the object detection app. after importing the model on my android studio. i have perform the following code to generate detection output:

```
val outputs=model.process(image)
val output=outputs.outputAsCategoryList
```

now here model contain the our model which process on image variable and generate the outputs. now main output is shown in the form of tensor category list.

output basically returns the three detections i.e. coordinates of bounding boxes ,label , confidence score. now i want to extract all these detail in separate variable using which I'll able to draw bounding boxes on image. so how i can extract these points?

Comment: First thing to try is to Log these data and see what format they are, or if you have access you can check what type of data outputAsCategoryList returns. Then based on this information use can use different approaches to get the data you want.